# How to run Vagrant on Windows with Ruby and Rack

Tags: ruby, windows, vagrant

I'm trying to run a VM with Vagrant on Windows 10.  Vagrant installed fine.  I tried to run `vagrant up --provision` and always got

```
The plugins failed to load properly. The error message given is
shown below.

cannot load such file -- rack
```

This seems like a Ruby problem, so I installed Ruby and Rack.  But Ruby is only recognized on my home directory,  not the directory of the application.

Comment: Where did you install Ruby and Rack? The host machine or in the VM? Are you using RVM or rbenv on your host machine? What does `gem env` on your host machine and the VM report? Copy its output and paste it into the question, formatted appropriately, without using "edited" or "updated" type tags.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I actually figured out it was that my virtualbox version was not compatible with vagrant.  Appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Could be that your local Ruby installation is missing Rack:

```
gem install rack
```

Comment: yea I had tried this.  Sorry for the late reply, It was actually happening because my virtualbox version was not compatible with vagrant.  But I appreciate the help.